# Power BI Embedded pricing

Tags: price, powerbi-embedded

I have a question regarding Power BI Embedded cost. I first try to select A1 node, but the description says that it provides 1-300 rendering per hour.  I wonder what if it is over 300, what happen.  I wonder if it is automatically changed to A2 node type, or if it is charged more. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Exceeding a capacity allocation does NOT automatically cause a scale up (i.e. A1 -> A2). What will happen is that the exceeding requests\renders will get pushed back or rejected from the Power BI servers, which will result in failed or very slow responses in case of embedding.

Comment: Please note, you CAN however, identify hours which larger traffic in your site and scale up to A2 (or more) just for a selected amount of time.